# JWT token in codeigniter (ion-auth)

Tags: ion-auth

I use ion auth for user authentication.

how to make JWT token in codeigniter.

send username and password and get token and refresh token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in default ion auth don't support JWT

but the solution:

1- edit ion_auth_model and create a function to check user and pass

2-use php jwt lib to make a token

https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt

regard